# When calling a recursive function to order values, it misses one. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, algorithm, function, recursion

I have a recursive function that reads a list of scout records from a file, and adds then in order of their ID's to a list box. The function is called with `addScouts(1)` The function is below:

```
def addScouts(self,I):
    i = I
    with open(fileName,"r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            if str(line.split(",")[3])[:-1] == str(i):
                self.scoutList.insert(END,line[:-1])
                i += 1
                return self.addScouts(i)
    return
```

My issue is that my file ID's are ordered `1,2,4,5` as at some point I removed the scout with ID of 3. However, when I run the function to re-order the scouts in the list box (the function above), it only lists the scouts up to and including ID 3. This is because when `i = 3`, none of the items in the file are equal to 3, so the function reaches the end and returns before it gets a chance to check the remaining records.

File contents:

```
Kris,Rice,17,1
Olly,Fallows,17,2
Olivia,Bird,17,4
Louis,Martin,18,5
```

Any idea's how to fix this?

Comment: Please add a sample of your file content too  +1 if you do that  .

Comment: What compelled you to use recursion here?

Comment: @DavidHammen It seemed the simplest way, and the one i understand the most, to order them. If you have another suggestion, please feel free to answer with that :)

Comment: if you want them in order why not just sort?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham If there is a way you think i can do this, please post in an answer

Comment: @AdminHydra - The last thing you want to do here is use recursion. Saying that "it seemed the simplest way" is an indicator of an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a bunch of different scouts, each with a last name, first name, age(?), and ID number. The ID numbers are unique, but otherwise otherwise meaningless. There are lots of ways to organize your data. For example, you could use those ID numbers as a key in a dictionary (in which case the order is apparently random). ...

Comment: How you store your data, how you use it, and how you present it are three very different things. You should write flexible code so that how you store it doesn't limit how you use it or how you present it. With regard to recursion being an awful choice, your code will have a lot of open file handles (on my computer, with default settings, I get 256), and you are reading through the file umpteen number of times. Just read the file in, line by line, storing each line as a new entity. Recursion is fun but it is an anti pattern here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just sort on the last column:

```
 sorted(f,key=lambda x: int(x.split(",")[-1]))
```

You can use bisect to find where to put the new data to keep the data ordered after it is sorted once:

```
from bisect import bisect
import csv
with open("foo.txt") as f:
    r = list(csv.reader(f)) 
    keys = [int(row[-1]) for row in r]
    new = ["foo","bar","12","3"]
    ind = bisect(keys, int(new[-1]))
    r.insert(ind,new)
    print(r)
```

Output:

```
[['Kris', 'Rice', '17', '1'], ['Olly', 'Fallows', '17', '2'], ['foo', 'bar', '12', '3'], ['Olivia', 'Bird', '17', '4'], ['Louis', 'Martin', '18', '5']]
```

A simpler way is to  check for the first row that has a higher id, if none are higher just append to the end:

```
import csv
with open("foo.txt") as f:
    r = list(csv.reader(f))
    new = ["foo","bar","12","3"]
    key = int(new[-1])
    ind = None
    for i, row in enumerate(r):
        if int(row[-1]) >= key:
            ind = i
            break
    r.insert(ind, new) if ind is not None else r.append(new)
    print(r)
```

Output:

```
 [['Kris', 'Rice', '17', '1'], ['Olly', 'Fallows', '17', '2'], ['foo', 'bar', '12', '3'], ['Olivia', 'Bird', '17', '4'], ['Louis', 'Martin', '18', '5']
```

To always keep that file in order when adding a new value we just need to write to a temp file, writing the line in the correct place and then replace the original with the updated file:

```
import csv
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from shutil import move


with open("foo.csv") as f, NamedTemporaryFile(dir=".", delete=False) as temp:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    wr = csv.writer(temp)
    new = ["foo", "bar", "12", "3"]
    key, ind = int(new[-1]), None
    for i, row in enumerate(r):
        if int(row[-1]) >= key:
            wr.writerow(new)
            wr.writerow(row)
            wr.writerows(r)
            break
        wr.writerow(row)
    else:
        wr.writerow(new)
move(temp.name, "foo.csv")
```

foo.csv after will have the data in order:

```
Kris,Rice,17,1
Olly,Fallows,17,2
foo,bar,12,3
Olivia,Bird,17,4
Louis,Martin,18,5
```

Comment: How would i apply this to the records in my file?

Comment: @AdminHydra,  if you always want the lines sorted by the last column then the code above will do exactly that. If you need to insert a value use bisect, I will add the code to keep the order adding new values

Comment: Sorry, could you include this in your answer? I'm new to this area of python

Comment: @AdminHydra, yes,  is the file currently sorted by id?

Comment: no, the file is a serial, so just appended to the bottom, hence why i need the ordering algorithm. So the file ID's could read `1,3,5,2,4` for example

Comment: But once sorted it will  change or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81131/discussion-between-admin-hydra-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 1):

You can check if your list has the same length as your file and if not, you run addScouts again, and if true, you end. Like this:

```
def addScouts(self,I):
    i = I
    with open(fileName,"r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            if str(line.split(",")[3])[:-1] == str(i):
                self.scoutList.insert(END,line[:-1])
                i += 1
                return self.addScouts(i)
    if len(scoutList) < len(lines):
        return self.addScouts(i+1)
    else:
        return
```